# How to Change a TextView with the values in an EditText

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

I am completely new to App making and I want to make something in which there are two EditTexts (number only), which are then divided and turned into a percentage and displayed in a TextView. Unfortunately, I have no idea if what I am doing is correct. Here is my code

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    public class FirstInformation extends Activity {

EditText eT4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
EditText eT5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
TextView tV6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_information);
    if (eT4 != null && eT5 != null){
        double numerator = (double) Integer.parseInt(eT4.getText().toString());
        double denominator = (double) Integer.parseInt(eT5.getText().toString());
        double textView = Math.round(numerator/denominator)*100;
        tV6.setText(textView+"");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.first_information, menu);
    return true;    
}


public void updateTextView() {
    if (eT4 != null && eT5 != null){
        double numerator = (double) Integer.parseInt(eT4.getText().toString());
        double denominator = (double) Integer.parseInt(eT5.getText().toString());
        double textView = Math.round(numerator/denominator)*100;
        tV6.setText(textView+"");
    }
    return;
}
```

}

Any feedback at all would be great. Thank you so much!

Comment: Why don't you use directly Double.parseDouble(String) instead of that casting?

Comment: "I have no idea if what I am doing is correct." The best way to find out is to run it and see if you get the expected results. If not then it is more helpful for us and you if you describe the expected results, the actual results, and any error messages/logcat

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById()` in `onCreate()`

[Division by zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is with the following code:

```
EditText eT4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
EditText eT5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
TextView tV6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
```

`findViewById` method returns `null` for all those calls because you're doing UI related tasks before the `setContentView` method has finished. So you can declare the variables there and then initialize them after `setContentView` method.

Answer (score 0):

Just as the other guys said, the `findViewById()` calls go into the `onCreate()` method otherwise they shall return null.

One other thing: `updateTextView()` is never called. You could use a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) or simply an onClickListener:

```
tv6.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        updateTextView();
    }
});
```

And the result will be updated every time you click on the result textView. By the way using a TextWatcher (with `afterTextChanged()` method) is a better practice. I suggest you to take a guide/tutorial and try that ;)